# Internal server error while sending a post request with Ktor

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, ktor

I am trying to make a simple API that allow me to query all elements. It lists all the data that is customer and  orders.

I have GET, POST, DELETE routes for both customers and orders. These orders and customer are data classes. Now when I'm trying to send a post request it gives an **500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR** and gives this error

> kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Customer' is not found.`

But I already annotated my `Customer` class with `@Serializable`.

My GET request works properly.

***Customer data class***

```
data class Customer(
    val id : String,
    val firstName : String,
    val lastName : String,
    val email : String,
)
val customerStorage = mutableListOf<Customer>()
```

***Order data class***

```
data class Order(
    val number: String, //Because it will contain a number with dashes
    val contents : List<OrderItem>,
)

@Serializable
data class OrderItem(
    val item : String,
    val amount : Int, //what is the amount of each item in each order
    val price : Double,
)

//place to store our orders
val orderStorage = listOf(Order(
    "2020-04-06-01", listOf(
        OrderItem("Ham Sandwich",2,5.50),
        OrderItem("Water",1,1.50),
        OrderItem("Beer",3,2.30),
        OrderItem("Cheesecake", 1,3.75)
    )

),
    Order("2020-04-03-01", listOf(
        OrderItem("Cheeseburger",1,8.50),
        OrderItem("Water", 2,1.50),
        OrderItem("Coke",2,1.76),
        OrderItem("Ice Cream", 1,2.35)
    ))
)
```

***Post route of customer***

```
post{
    val customer = call.receive<Customer>()
    customerStorage.add(customer) 
    call.respondText("Customer stored correctly", status = HttpStatusCode.Created)
}
```

I was referring [this tutorial](https://ktor.io/docs/creating-http-apis.html)

Comment: Please check that you added the `kotlinx.serialization` Gradle plugin https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#using-the-plugins-block and installed the `ContentNegotiation` plugin with appropriate converter https://ktor.io/docs/kotlin-serialization.html#register_converter.

Comment: Thanks [Aleksei Tirman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13963150/aleksei-tirman) for replying on this question. I have checked and i have already added the ```kotlinx.serialization``` Gradle plugin and since the converter i needed was only for JSON, so i have already installed ```ContentNegotiation``` with JSON Converter.

Comment: Since I cannot reproduce your problem, could you please share your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also referring to the tutorial that you mentioned. I faced the same error. I changed **ktor_version=1.6.5** to **ktor_version=1.6.1** and ran the project. It worked well.

***I think there's some issue with kotr version 1.6.5.***

Also, don't forget to add `kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.0"` in **build.gradle.kts** file. It should look like this:

```
plugins {
application
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.0"
kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.0" }
```